# Is UML a domain specific language (DSL)?

Tags: programming-languages, uml, dsl

Is it appropriate to think of UML as a DSL?

I know that everybody thinks of UML as a way to draw pictures, but underlying the "view" of UML diagrams there is a model...and the "L" in UML stands for Language.

Another question - is SysML a DSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML is NOT a DSL because UML can be used to model any vertical domain (insurance software, embedded systems,...)

UML is a (horizontal) DSL because UML is a specialized language to model software systems.

So UML is and is not a DSL depending on how you look at it. You could apply the same reasoning to many other languages like html or SQL. They are general because they can be used to represent/manipulate any kind of data but they are specific because they are focused on one task

Comment: I disagree about HTML and SQL.  HTML is clearly focused on describing how to render web pages.  SQL is clearly focused on manipulating sets of data organized as tables; yes, some SQL dialects have been extended with WHILE and ADD1 (making them essentially Turing capable), but nobody sane codes complete systems in HTML or (PL)SQL.

Comment: FWIW - Martin Fowler considers both XAML and XSL to be DSLs...my guess is that HTML and SQL are both DSLs.

Comment: The point is that there are several perspectives you can use to look at a language and a language can be general purpose from one perspective and DSL from other (whether a language has to be turing complete to be a DSL is a different discussion)

Comment: I agree with you 100%, while XSLT is Turing complete it is a DSL when used to transform XML documents (its domain and purpose).  It is a matter of perspective.

Comment: How is UML specialized to any horizontal domain, though? Class diagrams, for example, are used to represent meta-models, system architectures, Java implementations, and data schemata. It seems that UML is not domain-specific, no matter if vertical or horizontal domains are considered.

Answer (score 7):

UML *is* a DSL.

A "domain specific language" lets one specify a problem or a solution in a narrow area of application; banking, telephony circuit design, ....  One way to distinguish a DSL is that it cannot do general purpose computation (although there are some DSLs that can).  Java, C#, Python and COBOL fail this test. (Some would say COBOL is domain-specific for "business" but its only serious concession to that is a decimal data type, and C# has that too.)  ColdFusion fails this test; nonstandard syntax does not a DSL make, but IIRC ColdFusion has some support for generating HTML.  Fortran fails this test, but its array(-section) sublanguage is only good for arrays and not general purpose computation.  Verilog is very domain specific: it is designed to let you write down digital circuits.

UML focuses on specifying different aspects of how software is structured.  [You'll note it can't do general purpose computation; one hallmark].   (It actually has 9 or more different aspects it addresses: classes, statecharts, deployment, ... I'll stick to the class aspect for this discussion).  The class diagram aspect lets one describe how data is organized, and operations on that data.   You can argue this about software so it can't be "domain-specific".  What, building software isn't a problem domain?

SYSML is focused on expressing how systems are joined, so it fits this category too.

A more useful question to ask IMHO is, "If I think of UML as a DSL, what do I gain?"  Here I don't think you get a lot.   The concept of DSL is useful when you arguing for one you don't have (designed or possess) with the point being better expressiveness for a common problem, and might be useful for arguing "you don't want implement your system entirely in it because it isn't Turing capable".  It is also useful if you want to explain that your language is going to have a lot of funny notations, precisely because they serve special purposes.  People already know this about UML, so... nothing learned.

While I'm a big fan of DSLs, I'm also a big fan of GPLs (general purpose languages). I think in big systems you should necessarily find a "lot" of both: the DSLs to express what they can succinctly (cuts engineering and maintenance costs), and the GPLs to provide arbitrary computation and glue between the system parts.     For me what counts in a language is:

- what's the class of problem it claims to address and how well does it do it?
- what's the syntax (and is it relatively standard for the problem domain)?
- what are the precise semantics (this is where you learn the most)?
- how good is the tool support?
- how well does the DSL integrate into other parts of a big system?
- how big and supportive is the community?

UML has (after 15 years) arrived at pretty good answers to these questions.

Homegrown DSLs often don't do so well, partly due to poor design, but often due to the fact that tool support is difficult to get.   My company provides [machinery to give DSL builders excellent support](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/products/DMS/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) to improve this situation.

Comment: I think an important point you hit on here is that of execution.  Much of UML is just pretty diagrams to used to convey information to people to read.  However, other parts of UML are essentially executable by a computer.  I guess its those parts that could constitute a DSL...even more so when it is further constrained by UML profiles (like SysML is).

Comment: The concept of DSL and "executable" are orthogonal. You can have an executable DSL; Verilog is a perfect arcane example.  You can also have non-executable DSLs such as UML class diagrams or the Big-OH notation of computer science.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean directly executable, but involved in the execution of a computer program (as opposed to being only for human reading).  In his book on DSLs Martin Fowler points out CSS as a classic example of a DSL, which is itself, not directly executable.  On the other hand, I don't think (for example) Use Case Diagrams in UML qualify as a DSL because their only purpose is to be looked at by people.

Comment: Use Case Diagrams are a fine DSL.  They are a notation intended to convey something.  We can argue about whether the semantics are well defined ("people look at and interpret" is pretty sloppy), but to the extent such semantics are precise, one could use that DSL to arguably generate (abstract) test cases.

Comment: You are right...as long as the semantics are precise, I could write a computer program whose behavior would be governed by that information, thus turning it into a DSL.   As Jordi said, it seems to be a matter of *how* the information is used.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - NO - to both questions.

Think of UML as a tool that lets you describe software architectures, software interactions and so on ... describe them **in a general way**, language agnostic.

DSLs are **specialised** syntaxes meant to make it easier to describe some **specific set of problems**

Comment: Describing how data is organized in an application isn't a specialized problem?

Comment: If we talk about programming then no, because it relates to the whole programming languages, while DSLs are subsets of a programming language

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your first question depends on how to define "General" in  the term "General Purpose Language". [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) it is not a DSL:

> The opposite is:
>
> - a general-purpose programming language, such as C, Java or Python,
> - or a general-purpose modeling language such as the Unified Modeling    Language (UML).

Answer (score 1):

I am a MDA enthusiast so I think I can provide you a very detailed answer to your question. 
What is the UML:
The **Object Management Group** (OMG), a consortium of companies aimed at providing standard languages and technologies, defined a meta-meta modeling language called "The Meta Object Facility" or **MOF** (http://www.omg.org/mof). A meta-model is a model describing a model or, in other terms, describing the vocabulary (the elements you can use in a model), the syntax (ho they relate each other) and their semantics (what does each entity mean and how its meaning changes in a given context, etc.). A meta-model plays the same role played by Context-Free grammars with respect to the languages they produce. You can thus think at a meta-meta model as a language you can use to define meta-model. This is what the OMG actually did with the UML. The UML language has a meta-model described by means of the MOF in two documents: The **UML Infrastructure** and the **UML Supersturcture** (http://www.omg.org/spec/UML).

The UML meta-model has been defined with the aim of been generic enough to cope with the modeling of different systems belonging to different domains. When you define a new UML model you create an instance of the UML meta-model. You could do that for many reasons: to analyse some characteristics of the system, to share some aspects of the system with other stakeholders and so on. However, one of the most important aspects of the OMG vision are **model transformations**. You can think at a transformation as a set of rules telling an interpreter how to explore a model and produce something else. You can basically transform a model into two different kind of thins, other models (Model2Model, M2M transformations, defined by means of the **QVT** language) or text such as code or documentation (Model2Text, M2T, transformations defined by means of the **MOFM2T Transformation language**). So it is VERY IMPORTANT to understand that a UML model is not its diagram. A diagram is just a pictorical representation of the model contents, useful for umans, but not machine readable. You can't apply transformations to a diagram.

The **Eclipse Modeling Framework** (EMF) is a very powerful (and FREE!) framework implementing all the technologies I have mentioned. A subset of the MOF is implemented in the Eclipse ECORE language. By means of the ECORE the UML meta-model is defined so grafical UML editors (i.e. Papyrus, TopCased, etc.) actually creates XMI representation of the graphically defined UML models conform to the ECORE representation of the UML meta-model. Such representation can be provided as input to transformations engine. The two transformation languages, and related engines, are also available in the EMF with the QVTo plugin and **ACCELEO** (implementing the MOFM2T transformation language).

As mentioned UML is intentionally generic. However it also provide lightweight extension mechanisms to extends original language vocabulary with domain specific constructs. This can be done by means of stereotypes. A stereotype is a sort of label (actually with meta-attributes) you can attach on model elements to create new entities in the language. You can for instance say in your models some of the classes could be requirements or something else. There are of course some rules, for instance when you stereotype a meta-class you can not violate its original semantics, just reduce it.

SySML is a profile of the UML http://www.omgsysml.org/. A SysML Block is just a UML class stereotyped as Block, a SysML Requirement is just another UML class stereotyped as Block and so on.

Profiling a meta-model like the UML is a quite easy way of creating a sort of DSL (as with stereotypes you add to a more general language some constructs which belong to your domain) which is compatible with the UML (i.e. you can use SysML and UML together). There is another  way of creating a DSL which is defining its meta-model by means of the MOF (ECORE). In this case you create a brand new language which is conceptually at the same level of the UML itself.

Many people say UML is just about diagrams because in many cases they do not know what they are talking about. The topic is far more complex, interesting and promising.

Comment: Good material.  So it sounds like you are saying UML is NOT a DSL, but SysML (or any other UML profile) is a DSL.  Is this right?

Comment: well I intentionally avoid to answer the question as it is not that easy. The point is that UML has been defined to be general. In this sense it is definitely not a DSL. The Profiling (Stereotypes) mechanisms has been defined to allow the extensibility of the language. In this case it depends on what you mean with "Domain". If "System Engineering" is a domain then yes SySML is a DSL. If you need a more detailed granularity (i.e. Automotive, Avionics, etc.) then SysML is probably too generic and further profiling might be needed. It is an Ontological question bu UML is not a DSL by definition

Comment: Also consider that with the term DSL many refer to textual languages and use DSML (where M stands for Modeling) to refer to domain specific graphical languages. However such distinction is very pointless to me as UML, though providing a graphical notation, is a language such as C++, Java, etc. MOF defined meta-models are equivalent to Context Free grammars and viceversa. So such distinction, IMHO, contribute to create confusion among those thinking that modeling languages are just about pictures and that programs are not models themselves.

Comment: I meant that as a UML model can be considered a model of a C++ program, a C++ program can be considered a model of the assembly that could derived from it through compilation and so on. It is just about increasing/decreasing the level of abstractions but we are always dealing with models, languages and transformations of symbols.

Comment: OT: as you are from U.S., and I am from Italy, please check and correct my English (I understand that is not an easy task! :) )

Answer (score 0):

UML is a general modelling language that is not specific to any domain whilst the S in DSL stands for Specific.  UML is used for modelling systems that can also be represented by multi-purpose programming languages.  DSL on the other hand are constrained programming/scripting languages which are specific to a particular domain.

Comment: I think the U in UML stands for Unified.

Comment: You're right, it would have been a sweet tie in if it did stand for universal though <sigh>